# Drag 2 GameObjects simultaneously in Unity 2018

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, touch, game-development

I wanna to Drag two gameObjects simultaneously in Y-Axis so I have made this code but actually, It's just working for one gameObject to drag

I have tested a lot of ways to do that but I couldn't

Can you guys help me to do this?

Thanks a lot

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Drag2 : MonoBehaviour
{
private float dist;
private bool dragging = false;
private Vector3 offset;
private Transform toDrag;

void Update()
{
    Vector3 v3;


    if (Input.touchCount < 1)
    {
        dragging = false;
        return;
    }

    Touch[] touch = Input.touches;
    for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
    {
        Vector3 pos = touch[i].position;

        if (touch[i].phase == TouchPhase.Stationary)
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(pos);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && (hit.collider.CompareTag("Object")))
            {
                Debug.Log(Input.touchCount);
                toDrag = hit.transform;
                dist = hit.transform.position.z - Camera.main.transform.position.z;
                v3 = new Vector3(0, pos.y, dist);
                v3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3);
                offset = toDrag.position - v3;
                dragging = true;
            }
        }
        if (dragging && touch[i].phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            v3 = new Vector3(0, Input.mousePosition.y, dist);
            v3 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(v3);
            toDrag.position = v3 + offset;
        }
        if (dragging && (touch[i].phase == TouchPhase.Ended || touch[i].phase == TouchPhase.Canceled))
        {
            dragging = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, it cannot be done on your approach, since you are Looping trough the touches using Update. The most efficient way right now is by using ECS style of approach but I guess you are not ready for that. So I suggest another efficient way of handling it. By Implementing a Interface of touches in your Objects that can be dragged, you can accomplish this things 2 or more drags without Stressing the CPU on Update. Check the IEventSystemHandler documentation.

Comment: you can add them to a container game object as children. always ONLY move the container.

Comment: @Aizen Thanks for your answer. How implementing the interface will help me to move two game objects simultaneously?